# Convert decimal part of a double to integer? in JAVA

Tags: java, casting, int, double, decimal

I want my integer being as follows:

double number= 9.7361;

and I want my intenger have this: 7361.

another example:

double number2= 0.43;

and I want my integer have this: 43.

In Java.

Comment: What result do you want for `Math.PI`?

Comment: @BilltheLizard it returns 3.1415... but only to less than 16 digits...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you saying that you want 4 decimals as int?  If so,  what kind of rounding you need?

Comment: `9.7361` is just how the value is printed. This value is really `9.73610000000000042064129956997931003570556640625`

Comment: @Ricardo CM, do you have option to use BigDecimal and use integer and scale?

[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your question has an answer *so long as* you limit how far into the fractional part of the double you can go. For that slightly modified question, consider the following function:

```
public static int fracPartAsInt(double d, int digits){
    return (int)((d - ((int)d)) * Math.pow(10, digits));
}
```

First we isolate the fractional part of the double:

```
(d - ((int)d)
```

Then give `digits` digits by multiplying by `10^digits`

```
(d - ((int)d)) * Math.pow(10, digits)
```

Finally we discard the rest by truncating to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague atleast explain what you want to achieve by doing this  If its always for three decimal places you can do this.

```
double d=9.7681;
int a =d%1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to separate integral and fractional parts and convert them to strings separately. Following are the detailed steps.

1) Extract integer part from floating point.

2) First convert integer part to string.

3) Extract fraction part by exacted integer part from n.

4) If d is non-zero, then do following.

….a) Convert fraction part to integer by multiplying it with pow(10, d)

….b) Convert the integer value to string and append to the result.